# Fullcalendar not displaying properly in an iframe in Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, iframe, fullcalendar

In my application I have a 'Calendar' tab which when clicked should display an iframe with a Fullcalendar (2.2.5). The event list is populated by a JSON fetch from the DB.

This works fine in Chrome but in Firefox and IE it only displays the buttons but not the calendar grid.

If you right click on the iframe and reload it does load. I also noticed when refreshing the page if I click on the Calendar tab before the default tab loads it will display as expected.

I've tried hardcoding the events, date formatting to ISO8601. When I enter the FC URL in a new tab it loads in all browsers.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Solution-

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
         var n = $("#tabs").tabs("length");

         if (ui.index == n - 1) {             

            if (calendarLoaded == false) {
                var html = [];
                html.push('<div id="calendar">');
                html.push('<iframe src="../../fullcalendar/index.php"></iframe>');
                html.push('</div>');
                $('#calendar').append(html.join(""));
                calendarLoaded = true;
            }

         }...
```

Comment: From the console I get this error in Firefox "TypeError: this.rowEls is null"

Comment: I have solved this, the issue was loading the Jquery tabs and the calendar iframe at the same time before the calendar was ready. I got around this by adding the HTML for the calendar iframe when the calendar tab was clicked on.